# Why isn't the final render properly matching the viewport preview? (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, light

I have been facing a ridiculous issue with trying to render an image for a GFX project. No matter what sorts of settings I tweak in the **Render properties**, I always get an ugly, much darker result that looks very different from what I am seeing in the viewport. The shading that I originally set for the objects doesn't match the render, nor do the shadows match. I have spent all day trying to resolve this issue with no luck. Please explain what the issue is and why it is happening + thanks for any help.

> Color Management settings:

- **Display Device**: sRGB < Same for "Sequencer"
- **View Transform**: Standard
- **Look**: Base Contrast
- **Exposure**: 1.00
- **Gamma**: .75

[image]
Rendered image
[image]
Viewport preview

Comment: In the Outliner (top right window) make sure that you've enabled the lamp visibility for render (camera icon, to display it, click on the filter icon)

Comment: Don't. Make sure all your lights are enabled for rendering and just render to OpenEXR for "SFX" (whatever that means) and you're literally done.

Comment: reset the gamma to 1.

Comment: Okay, so from what Moonboots said, the lights in the outliner **are** enabled for rendering, which doesn't make any sense because the other issue is that literally the material I'm using on all of the character's limbs are not working either. I'm literally about to lose my mind because this issue seems unresolvable.